# jquery and checkbox data via ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a set of checkboxes that I can check and send over ajax.

What I'm looking to do ideally is to send several pieces of information via ajax to a php script, `the checkbox that has been checked` and also an `id`

The `id` is based on the URL, so I can get that using a `$_GET['id']`.

So if the user checked both boxes, the values that need to be sent to the php script will be:

`53`
`57`
`1` - where this value is a value in the URL.

I have the following so far:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="53" id="part_shipping" />
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="57" id="part_shipping" />
<input name="confirm" type="button" value="confirm" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
   $(":checked").each(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
         id = 'id:1';
         data = 'shipping:' + value;
         console.log(data);
   });
    $.post("ajax.php", data);   
});

</script>
```

How do I append the id within the data so it reads:
`shipping:53
shipping:57
id:1`

Comment: Maybe place the id in a hidden field when rendering the page? (But I think hidden fields are bad practice)

Comment: but how do i get that in the `data`? Appending it to the end of `data` gives me `531`, `571` etc I need `53`, `57`, `1`

Comment: get the id from the url using $_GET['id'] and then add it onto another field. Something along the lines of `echo '<input type="hidden" value=' . $_GET['id'] . '>';` You are going to have to send the hidden field to ajax.php as well.

Comment: I can do that, i meant, how do i then pass that to the `data`? So far `data` only contains the checkbox values, not the hidden field value as well?

Comment: change `id = 'id:1';` to something along the lines of `id = 'id' +  idValue;` where `idValue` is the value of the hidden field (do the same thing you are doing for `data = 'shipping:' + value;` but change it for the id field.

Comment: Got it working with: $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
   var order_id = $('#order_id').val();
   $(":checked").each(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
  
   $.post("ajax.php", { value: value, order_id: order_id}, function(data) {
   }); 
  });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `<input>` tags are not already inside a `<form>`, then add one:

```
<form id="myForm">
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="53" id="part_shipping" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="57" id="part_shipping" />
    <input name="confirm" type="button" value="confirm" />
    ...
</form>
```

Now, you can use jQuery's `.serialize()` to compose a data string of the format "name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3" etc., where the names are as given in the HTML :

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').click( function() {
        $.post("ajax.php", $("#myForm").serialize());   
    });
});
```

Checkboxes will only appear in the serialized form if they are checked. And I think I'm right in saying that the button won't be included in the serialization.

The advantage of doing it this way is that the script is responsive to design changes in the form. If you add or remove a field, the javascript does not need to be changed.